# can gunzip work on file without a suffix?

Tags: linux, gzip, gunzip

Is there a way to `gunzip` a file that isn't ending with a `.zip` even though I know for a fact the file is indeed a zip?

Comment: Similar on Unix: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32953/gzip-decompress-on-file-with-other-extension

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two issues here.  gunzip can be used to decompress any single file compressed with gzip regardless of the file's extension.

gunzip < file > output file

A zip file (one containing multiple compressed files) is incompatible with gunzip.  For this kind of file, you need to use unzip.  unzip can decompress any zip file (not gzip) regardless of extension.

http://www.info-zip.org/UnZip.html

Answer (score 2):

`gunzip` works with `gzip` (".gz") files, not `zip` (".zip") files. For `zip` files, you need to use the `unzip` command.

Also, the extension doesn't matter in linux, and is simply for human-reference. `gunzip` is complaining because the markers inside the file you are trying to decompress indicate that the file is *not* a LZ77 file, which is what `gunzip` is designed to handle. It is either corrupt, or you need a different tool to decompress it. If it's really a `zip` file, then you need the tool I described above.